# geth archive data location

Tags: go-ethereum, archive-node

i cant seem to find this in the docs - i want to run a geth full archive node. I have the NVME space for the current data but i need a new drive for the historical data.

is there a flag or setting for the location of the archive data? i did not see it here https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options

edit: is it `--datadir.ancient` ??

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between archive and full is in the garbage collection - a full node verifies all the state on the chain, but doesn't keep it all. An archive does. As such, the setting you're looking for isn't in the `--syncmode` flag, but rather:

```
--gcmode archive
```

You can find that in the [Geth command line docs](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options), or in [this](https://blog.ethereum.org/2018/02/14/geth-1-8-iceberg%C2%B9/) Geth blog post in the section "Breaking Changes". There's also some discussion about `--gcmode archive` in this StackExchange [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57710/what-is-gcmode-archive-in-geth).

**Update**: I just realized that I literally read the question wrong, and that the OP is looking for information on storing `ancient` data in a different location than the "regular" chaindata while running an archive node.

The command line flag for storing `ancient` data in a different location is indeed `--datadir.ancient`. It was announced in the EF blog from the Geth team [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/#freezer). If memory serves me right, the node might not immediately move all data into `ancient`, and it might be a more gradual process, perhaps explaining why the OP is not seeing an immediate change.

I figure I'll keep the old information about running an archive node up just in case someone else lands here looking for it.

Comment: I was looking for a different place to store `archive` data - which i confused with `ancient` data. it looks like this isnt currently possible with GETH or TG. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To store all the chain data is `--datadir /your/path/to/drive/here`. `--datadir.ancient` is for ancient states which will not generally be needed too much, usually used to mitigate the large file space required onto a HDD. if yo do not specify  `--datadir.ancient` it will default to your `--datadir` path

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I currently am running a full node and i want to switch to an archive node. I dont have the space on my nvme for the archive/ancient data. I set gcmode to archive and the datadir.ancient to my HDD but it doesnt seem to be storing any data on the hdd. I am trying to confirm that datadir.ancient will store the archive mode data. thanks.

Comment: if you want to switch to a archive node, you will need to restart. delete the data the full node created. datadir.ancient is old states, you wont need it once you are already synced. btw, you cannot sync an archive node on a HDD. you MUST sync onto a ssd. @D3l_Gato